# NavigationItem's titleView not animating correctly

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have looked at all the similar questions I could find and I have not found a solution to this problem.

I am setting the `titleView` property like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

The view controller is part of a navigation stack. When you tap on a row in in the previous view controller it pushes this controller onto the stack. Completely normal UINavigationController stuff.

As this view controller begins to animate in, the label appears at the origin (top left) and then stays there until the view controller finishes animating and then it jumps (no animation) to the proper position in the middle of the nav bar.

After tapping on the back button the title view animates out correctly, just like a normal title would.

Here is the code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.backgroundColor = .red
label.text = "test"
label.sizeToFit()
self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

Things I've tried:

- Specify a frame: no change. Plus I don't want to specify a frame. I don't want to make assumptions about the height of the nav bar.
- Moved it to `viewWillAppear`: no change.
- Moved it to `viewDidAppear`: better but still not right. The label does not appear at all until the animation is complete and then it appears where it should, no animation it just appears. The correct behaviour is to animate in from right to left like a normal title would.

This is easily reproducible with the Master-Detail project template in Xcode. If you want to try it just add the code above to the top of `configureView()` in `DetailViewController.swift`. In that template the navigation item's title is hardcoded into the storyboard. You can easily remove it by searching for "Detail". Click the result that says `Navigation Item: Title = "Detail"` and then remove the string from the Inspector pane.

---

**Update**

@synndicate's suggestion does work perfectly for the `UILabel` example above. But my real problem is with a `UIStackView`. When I use a stack view following the approach @synndicate suggests I get yet another animation problem. This time the title view starts sliding in but animates all the way to the origin. When the animation is finished it snaps to where it should be.

Here's the code in `prepare(for:sender:)` as @synndicate suggests...

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.backgroundColor = .red
label.text = "test"
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect.zero)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
stackView.sizeToFit()
controller.navigationItem.titleView = stackView
```

Any further suggestions?

Also, this is Xcode 8 and iOS 10.

**Update 2**

I have discovered that the stack view code above animates perfectly (just like an ordinary title would) in `viewDidLoad` for a view controller where the root of the nav hierarchy is a `UINavigationController`. The problem occurs when the root of the nav hierarchy is a `UISplitViewController`.

So I guess I could update my question to this...

How do I configure a `UIStackView` that will be set on the `navigationItem`'s `titleView` property where the root of the navigation hierarchy is a `UISplitViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to move the code to before you push the view controller on the stack?

e.g. In `MasterViewController.swift` of the Master-Detail project

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {                    

                let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true

                let label = UILabel()
                label.textAlignment = .center
                label.backgroundColor = .red
                label.text = "test"
                label.sizeToFit()

                controller.navigationItem.titleView = label

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In response to your update, at this point I would suggest you have to refactor and subclass UINavigationController where you set up your titleView there. And then in future `prepare(for:sender)` calls you can just set the text specific to the controller being pushed

Answer (score 0):

If you want the stackView to appear on a specific view controller of the navigation stack, simply add it in the view controller

```
self.view.addSubview(stackView)
```

Comment: Correct. But it's not going just anywhere. I'm trying to use a stack view in the navigation item's `titleView`. All the details are above.

Comment: why do you need to add it as `titleView`? `titleView` is meant to be used _only_ for views that are persistent throughout the navigation.

Comment: I want multiple labels in the title of the nav bar. My understanding is that each view controller can set its navigationItem's `titleView` just like `title`.